# Find same object id in odoo 7

Tags: python, odoo

I am trying to find same object in Odoo using search. I get back nothing or just "[]" from my search.

This is my code:

```
values = []
get_own_data = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
for get_own in get_own_data:
    get_date = self.pool.get('account.move').search(cr, uid, [('date', 'like', get_new.year)])
    if get_date:
        for new_data in get_date:
            datas = self.pool.get('account.move').browse(cr, uid, new_data)
            for data in datas.line_id:
                product_categ = self.pool.get('product.category').search(cr, uid, [("property_account_income_categ", "=", data.account_id)])
                print product_categ
                print "================"
```

I don't understand why I got nothing. The result doesn't give me good information.

Comment: Try like this:
Insted of this line;
datas = self.pool.get('account.move').browse(cr, uid, new_data)

Use this:
datas = self.pool.get('account.move').browse(cr, uid, get_date(new_data))

Comment: The only way this happen is that you don't have data match the domain that you use, or you are using bad domain witch search is not returning the record. and in the second search i think you should replace `[("property_account_income_categ", "=", data.account_id)]` by `[("property_account_income_categ", "=", data.account_id.id)]` in domain don't pass an object pass the id of th object